# Yii2 : Getting image id from html in controller

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using **`Yii2`**-advanced template. I want to take '`img_id`' from my '*index.php*' in **`siteController`**'s function.

My code in 'index.php' is as follows:

```
<?php
  $m = $dataProvider->getModels();
  foreach ($m as $dp) {
      echo '<a id ="img_id" class="" href="http://localhost/efa-webv1/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/subcat&id='.$dp['bmc_id'].'" method="post">';
      echo "<img src = '"."http://localhost/efa-webv1/backend/web/".$dp['bmc_image']."' />";
      echo '<center><font color = "white">'.$dp['bmc_name'].'<font/></center>';
      echo '</a>';
   } 
?>
```

And I'm trying to take it in my `siteController` as:

```
public function actionSubcat() {

    $searchModel = new BusinessMainCategoriesSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = $dataProvider->getTotalCount();
    $query = new \yii\db\Query;
    $query->select('*')->from('business_sub_categories')->where(['bmc_id' => $_POST["img_id"]]);    //trying to get img_id using this
    $query->createCommand();

    $dataProvider2 = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => false,
     ]);
     return $this->render('subcat', [
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2]);
    }
```

But if I used '$_POST["img_id"]', it says undefined index "img_id".

So, please help me to let me understand it.

[If I used Yii2 ancher tag, I get unexpected result as -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRoia.png)

Comment: Use [yii2 anchor tag](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#a%28%29-detail), it will be easier than this.

Comment: first check you will get img_id in $_POST

Comment: check it use in start of function print_r($_POST);

Comment: But I don't know how to work with nested php tags. That is I'm already using a <?php ?> tag in my index.php. And now if I want to use yii2 ancher tag, it will be something like this <?= Html::a(....)>. But when I tried this, it's the nested tag again....

Comment: I've also tried it with echo. but then, it displays Html::a('img_id', ['site/subcat', 'id' =>6], ['class' => 'profile-link'])
Travel
Html::a('img_id', ['site/subcat', 'id' =>7], ['class' => 'profile-link']) & so on... on our html

Comment: try: `Html::a(Html::img(path to image),['controller/action', 'id' => 'your_id']),`

Comment: I tried this now, but the link is not applied. there is no any link

Comment: If I used yii2 ancher tag, I get unexpected result. I'm updating the question above with screenshot. please refer to it.

Comment: it's your view or index file and you are using detailview or gridview?

Comment: No, I;m not using any view

Comment: But, recently I've noticed that I'm doing mistake with rendering to index from siteController's actionSubcat. I think that I should render from my actionIndex(). Isn't it? I'm extremely sorry about that....!

Comment: I'm confused!!! please look at my scenario : firstly, If I will click on image/link existing on my index page, it should go on 'site/subcat'. Then in which controller, I should write the code for it (that is, actionIndex / actionSubcat ) ?

Comment: It's fine now. I solved my issue. Thanks to all for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Now, my modified index.php is :

```
<?php
                    $m = $dataProvider->getModels();
                    foreach ($m as $dp) {
                        echo '<a id ="img_id" class="" href="http://localhost/efa-webv1/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/subcat&img_id='.$dp['bmc_id'].'" method="get">';
                        echo "<img src = '"."http://localhost/efa-webv1/backend/web/".$dp['bmc_image']."' />";
                        echo '<center><font color = "white">'.$dp['bmc_name'].'<font/></center>';
                        echo '</a>';
                    } ?>
```

I was taking &id instead of &img_id (in url) as referred in controller, it was wrong. now my controller code is like this -

```
$query->select('*')->from('business_sub_categories')->where(['bmc_id' => $_GET['img_id']]);
```

Please note that, when I was using POST method to pass values from url, it was not working. So, I used GET method & got it done.

Anyway, thanks to all!